# Need help replicating our UI. Moving the settings screen from RecyclerView to PreferenceFragmentCompat (AndroidX)

Tags: android, androidx, preferencefragment

We are moving our current settings screen from a RecyclerView based implementation to PreferenceFragmentCompat (AndroidX) due to accessibility reasons.

UI requirements:

- Screen Background gradient (Green to Black)
- White background for each setting item

We have not been able to achieve this even after spending days on it.

[image: Settings screen screenshot]

Comment: have you tried with applying styles

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't help.

Comment: Please post your code, XML and style, also gradle dependencies

Comment: Sure will do tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: What's the actual issue you are facing here? I can't tell what is wrong from the screenshot and what you have described